# Timemout in python multithread/multiprocess worker

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write program which executes time consuming tasks in parallel. I'd like to limit task execution time using signal within worker. Is it going to work? Any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you goal, trying to implement a multi-task operation on your own might be extremely time consuming and error prone. I would suggest you look into pre-made frameworks, such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), which handle these exact tasks and allow, among other things, to set timeouts on tasks and so-forth.